# Creating a trading card simple website page

Tags: html, css

I should be doing a animal trading card simple page per my training to look like this using HTML and linking CSS style from another style.css sheet;

[image]

Here's the code i used below, but when i run {even though I'm almost there} i get these errors:

The trading card page with styling has an info section below the image with class 'animal-info'
The #card element does not have class 'animal-info': expected false to equal true
Stacktrace

The border should be solid: expected 'none' to equal 'solid'
Stacktrace

The trading card page with styling has a border around the animal's info section
The border should be solid: expected 'none' to equal 'solid'
Stacktrace

The trading card page with styling has spacing between the border and card elements
There must be some padding around the outside border: expected 0 to be above 0
Stacktrace

```css
/* add your CSS here */
<style>


container { border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {border: 2px solid black;
}


#card {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em;
}
.animal-info {
border: 2px solid black;
}
ul {list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
li span { font-weight: bold;
}

h1{
  padding: 1em;
}

img {
  padding: 1em;
}

#summary{
  padding: 1em;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>For the Love of Puppies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Puppies</h1>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/300/300" alt="Puppy">
    <div class="animal-info">
    <div id="card">
      <p id="interesting-fact">Queen Elizabeth II has long been associated with
        Corgis. After a visit to Thomas Thynne, 5th Marquess of Bath in 1933,
        Princesses Elizabeth and Margaret made it well known to their family
        that they liked the Corgis owned by the Marquess.</p> </div>
     
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Dog Breed Group</span>: Herding Dogs
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>: 10 inches to 1 foot tall at the shoulder
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 12 to 14 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Weight</span>: Up to 30 pounds
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Welsh Corgis come in two varieties: the Pembroke and
        the Cardigan. They were registered as one breed by the Kennel Club in
        the U.K. until 1934, although many breeders believe the two breeds
        developed separately. Both have similar heads, bodies, levels of
        intelligence and herding ability, but the Cardigan is slightly
        larger and heavier boned than the Pembroke.
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What should I do for it to be like the reference page? It's driving me freakin' nuts.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: well, you defined the container as an `id` but in the CSS file you have used the class selector `.` , that's the reason it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I am created this card using simple css code.

```css
container { border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.container {border: 2px solid #eee;
}


#card {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em;
}
.animal-info {
border: 2px solid #eee;
}
ul {list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
li span { font-weight: bold;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
}
#summary{
  padding: 1em;
}

div#container {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px 10px #eee;
}
h1{margin-top:0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>For the Love of Puppies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Puppies</h1>
    <img src="https://placedog.net/300/300" alt="Puppy">
    <div class="animal-info">
    <div id="card">
      <p id="interesting-fact">Queen Elizabeth II has long been associated with
        Corgis. After a visit to Thomas Thynne, 5th Marquess of Bath in 1933,
        Princesses Elizabeth and Margaret made it well known to their family
        that they liked the Corgis owned by the Marquess.</p> </div>
     
      <ul id="facts">
        <li>
          <span>Dog Breed Group</span>: Herding Dogs
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Length</span>: 10 inches to 1 foot tall at the shoulder
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Average Lifespan</span>: 12 to 14 years
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Weight</span>: Up to 30 pounds
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p id="summary">Welsh Corgis come in two varieties: the Pembroke and
        the Cardigan. They were registered as one breed by the Kennel Club in
        the U.K. until 1934, although many breeders believe the two breeds
        developed separately. Both have similar heads, bodies, levels of
        intelligence and herding ability, but the Cardigan is slightly
        larger and heavier boned than the Pembroke.
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.I tried it but gave me the same 3 errors. I dunno what's wrong?! 

The trading card page with styling has an info section below the image with class 'animal-info'
The #card element does not have class 'animal-info': expected false to equal true

The trading card page with styling has a border around the entire card
The border must have a width greater than 0: expected 0 to be above 0

The trading card page with styling has a border around the animal's info section
The border should be solid: expected 'none' to equal 'solid'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the replies. I found the problem was putting the class="animal-info" code into the id=card instead of a standalone  above it. That seemed to fix it all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing CSS from scratch like you are doing is probably not the easiest way to do it. I recommend you to use a framework. For example I made this with Vuetify:

https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/qBbYrjG?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fcards%2F

[image]

Vuetify already contains the [Card element](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#cards) that looks very similar to what you are looking for. The card element is tag-named `<v-card></v-card>`. You can also add many other elements from here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/. Vuetify is fully responsive and will adjust automatically to fit different device sizes.